# Websocket connection fails while socket.io works fine

Tags: vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to establish a websocket connection with Websocket in my Vue project. But I get this error every time

> ```
> WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:3000/' failed:
> ```

The code I use for this:

```
onMounted(() => {
  const socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:3000/');
```

Also tried ws:// and different browsers (because some people on SO say it's a known Chrome problem).

But when I use socket.io for the same purpose, everything works fine

```
onMounted(() => {
  const socketio = io('localhost:3000');
```

On a server side I use socket.io. But I also tried ws:

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 4000 });

wsServer.on("connection", (client) => {
  console.log("connected!!!");

  client.send("hello!");
});
```

And then tried to connect using port 4000:

```
onMounted(() => {
  const socket = new WebSocket(`wss://localhost:4000/`);
```

Still can't connect...

I have a restriction to not use socket.io but use built-in Websocket instead. So I'm wondering what's the difference between Websocket and socket.io connections in this case? And how do I make the Websocket code work?

P.S. added Vue tag because maybe I should edit the configuration of my project?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state what type of server your using, but since connecting with the socket.io client works, I guess your server probably uses socket.io.

And as [the socket.io documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/#what-socketio-is-not) states:

> Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation.

And

> a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server

Socket.io is a library with a server and client side implementation, which uses WebSockets, but has a lot of features that make implementing real time connections easier.

So it seems like you have to use the socket.io client (although I understand this is a problem for you), or change the server implementation to a pure WebSocket implementation.

Comment: So if I want to connect to some service via websocket (binance or some news feed) then I can't use socket.io because it might be they don't use socket.io on their server?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK both server and client need to use socket.io, because socket.io uses a specific handshake to connect.